# In Typescript, create a new string Type consisting of only names of the sub-classes of a specified super-class

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics

What is the best way to create new string Type that only includes the names of the derived classes of a particular base class. For example: if A is the super and A1, A2, A3 etc. are derived classes, the new type `SubClassName` should only allow the assignment of those derived class names in string form.

```
class A {}
class A1 extends A{}
class A2 extends A{}
class AnyChildOfA extends A{}

// want to achieve this but don't want to manually add the new derived or child class each time something changes

type SubClassStrName = 'A1' | 'A2' | 'AnyChildOfA';

// This line is invalid syntax, but might tell what is desired
type SubClassName<T> = <? extends T>.constructor.name;
```

Comment: No way to do this automatically.